# BottlePy - returning TypeError: unhashable type: 'set' with %if clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

I'm trying to create a very simple HTML form using Bottle and Python 3.6. I want to have a form with two options, but I want to be able to send the default option to the form directly from python.

My test code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bottle import route, template, request, post, run

@route('/')
def test_1():

    return template('test.html',
                    selected="F")

@post('/')
def response():
    pass

run(host='localhost', port=8409)
```

This calls an HTML template that is as follows (saved as test.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="/">

        %if {{selected}} == "T":
            <input type="radio", name="sel", value="T" checked>T<br>
            <input type="radio", name="sel", value="F">F<br>
        %else:
            <input type="radio", name="sel", value="T">T<br>
            <input type="radio", name="sel", value="F" checked>F<br>
        %end

        <input type='submit' value='submit'>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rogerio\Python VENV\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "C:\Users\Rogerio\Python VENV\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1740, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "G:/My Drive/Data Technology/Python/temp.py", line 9, in test_1
    selected="F")
  File "C:\Users\Rogerio\Python VENV\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3619, in template
    return TEMPLATES[tplid].render(kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rogerio\Python VENV\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3409, in render
    self.execute(stdout, env)
  File "C:\Users\Rogerio\Python VENV\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3396, in execute
    eval(self.co, env)
  File "G:\My Drive\Data Technology\Python\test.html", line 11, in <module>
    %if {{selected}} == "T":
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

It seems that the problem is with the %if command, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Also, is there a more "proper" way of passing default values to the forms?

Thank you!

Comment: Try taking out the {{}}. It seems to be putting your variable into a set, which it cannot compare with a String.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 That was simple enough!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bottle templates, the `{{foo}}` syntax is for output. You shouldn't use it unless you want to "print" the variable (as in send it to the browser with the html).

To use `%if` you can just refer to the variable as normal:

```
%if selected == "T":
```

Comment: Thank you! This was not clear to me. It works after I made the change.